# Put constraint on max (or min) predicted value (mgcv)

Tags: logistic, binomial-distribution, splines, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I want to fit my data using a logistic GAM model with cubic regression splines. I know for sure that in reality my estimated probability should not go above 0.5 (due to mislabeling). So I thought about setting a constraint on my knots so they can not have any fitted values above .05. I've read the `pcls()` help file in the `mgcv` package but it only talks about setting monotonicity in Gaussian models. I'm not sure if this is even possible with binomial models.

Some sample data:

```r
Class1 = runif(1000, -100, 100)
Class2 = c(rnorm(200,0), runif(1000,-100,100))

Class1 = data.frame(x=Class1, Class1=TRUE)  
Class2 = data.frame(x=Class2, Class1=FALSE)  
dat    = rbind(Class1, Class2)
hist(dat$x, breaks=100)
```

How the data looks:

[image: a busy cat]

```r
fit = gam(Class1 ~ s(x, bs='cr', k=30), data=dat, family=binomial)
plot(fit)
```

As you can see, the spline is (unnecessarily) very wiggly around 0 (linear response, or .5 after logit transformation).

[image: a busy cat]

```r
hist(fit$fitted.values, xlim=c(0,1), xlab="P(Class 1)",
     main='Histogram of probabilities of being in Class 1', breaks=20)
```

As you can also see in the plot below there are many observations with a estimated probability above 0.5. There should be a hard constraint at 0.5.

[image: a busy cat]

What would be the best way to set a constraint at .5 if possible? I also thought about fitting my model and getting all the knots that are above 0.5 and manually set them at 0.5, but again I don't really know how this should be done.